# Fail to initialize plugin stackleak_plugin.so

Tags: gcc, dkms, displaylink

I'm on `Fedora 28`, Kernel `4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64` and trying to get a working dual-screen on a D6000 Dell docking Station.

For now I have the following error while trying to restart the displaylink service.

```
systemctl restart displaylink.service
Job for displaylink.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

journalctl -xe
modprobe: FATAL: Module evdi not found in directory /lib/modules/4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64
displaylink.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
displaylink.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start DisplayLink Manager Service.

modprobe evdi
modprobe: FATAL: Module evdi not found in directory /lib/modules/4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64
```

I tried to build the evdi module

```
sudo dkms status
evdi, 1.6.0: added

sudo dkms install evdi/1.6.0
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64 all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64/build/include KVERSION=4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64 DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.20.14-100.fc28.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.6.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

By looking at the log it seems there is an issue with the stakleak gcc plugin

```
cat /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.6.0/build/make.log
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:291: /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.6.0/build/evdi_modeset.o] Error 1
cc1: error: incompatible gcc/plugin versions
cc1: error: fail to initialize plugin ./scripts/gcc-plugins/stackleak_plugin.so
```

and now I'm lost. Can I disable this plugin ?